# CUBA Platform get username in Polymer UI

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, cuba-platform

What is the proper way to get a session parameters (like username of currently logged user) in Polymer UI.

I've expected something like:

```
Your login: [[msg('session$userLogin')]]
```

but not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no direct access to session params in Polymer UI. If you just need to display user login there is a [special method](http://files.cuba-platform.com/swagger/#!/UserInfo/get_userInfo) in REST API.

Here is the example of a component which loads and displays user login: https://gist.github.com/web-devel/3659ef13ccaefc6597e1ae649dcb42cf

If you need to access other session params you can create a [middleware service](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.5/service_creation.html) and [make it available](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.5/rest_api_v2_services_config.html) in REST API

Comment: It seems that is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you :)